# Run cron with an interval of 12 hours

Tags: linux, shell

This cron will run every day at 0.00 and 12 PM. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
0 */12 * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1

2013-12-31 00:00:00 UTC
2013-12-31 12:00:00 UTC
2014-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
2014-01-01 12:00:00 UTC
2014-01-02 00:00:00 UTC
...
```

But if I want to run the script at 08.00 AM and 08.00 PM every day. This is possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
0 8-20/12 * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or

```
0 8,20 * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
0 8,20 * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

A quicker solution might be there, but having 2 entries in this case isn't a big trouble I guess

```
0 8 * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
0 20 * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

The interval notation `*/12` does not guarantee 0 and 12, it only guarantees interval. For specific hours like 8 AM and 8 PM, replace the hour with the exact hours instead of intervals.

```
0 8,20 * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I believe `*/12` *does* guarantee 0 and 12, though the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) isn't 100% clear on that point.

Comment: @Keith Thompson - I hope so too that it guarantees 0 and 12. I already have the habit of using `0-23/2` for even hours and `1-23/2` for odd hours when running jobs every other hour.